# How to add only outer outline to UILabel on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

How to add an outer outline to UILabel like below.

[image: outline label]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass UILabel to get this effect

```
public class StrokedLabel: UILabel{
    internal var mOutlineColor:UIColor?
    internal var mOutlineWidth:CGFloat?

    @IBInspectable var outlineColor: UIColor{
        get { return mOutlineColor ?? UIColor.clear }
        set { mOutlineColor = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable var outlineWidth: CGFloat{
        get { return mOutlineWidth ?? 0 }
        set { mOutlineWidth = newValue }
    }

    override public func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset
        let textColor = self.textColor

        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        c?.setLineWidth(outlineWidth)
        c?.setLineJoin(.round)
        c?.setTextDrawingMode(.stroke)
        self.textColor = mOutlineColor;
        super.drawText(in:rect)

        c?.setTextDrawingMode(.fill)
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        super.drawText(in:rect)

        self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
let strokeTextAttributes = [ 
NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor : UIColor.red,
NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth : -4.0,
NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)]
as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
//Making outline here
labelOutLine.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: “Your outline text”, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
```

check this.. https://medium.com/@nimjea/custom-label-effects-in-swift-4-69ec12ba2178